# wordpress custom filter for the edit.php custom posts list

Tags: wordpress, filter, custom-post-type

I have a custom orders posts and i wish to implement an additional filter for the list view (a select drop) in the admin menu.

I have been messing with this for hours but couldn't find a solution.
i wish to filter the posts by several meta keys and values and by post date
this is the code im using for this matter

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'order_posts_filter' );

function order_posts_filter( $query ){
    global $pagenow,$wpdb;
    $type = 'post';
    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['post_type'];
    }
    if ( 'orders' == $type && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']) && $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'] != '') {
        $query->query_vars['post_date'] = $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'];
    }
    if ( 'orders' == $type && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_STATUS_VALUE']) && $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_STATUS_VALUE'] != '') {
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'order_status';
        $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_STATUS_VALUE'];
    }
    return $query;
}
```

What am i doing wrong here ?
my $_GET parameters are working as expected and i am getting the relevant data from the select boxes.

thanks

Comment: You haven't told us what isn't happening correctly? Is it not filtering?

Comment: only the second filter is applied when im trying to filter by both fileds

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this:

```
function wpse454363_posts_filter( $query ){
global $pagenow;
$type = 'post';
if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
    $type = $_GET['post_type'];
}
if ( 'product' == $type && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php') {
    $meta_query = array(); // Declare meta query to fill after
    if (isset($_GET['post_date']) && $_GET['post_date'] != '') {
        // first meta key/value
        $meta_query[] = array (
            'key'      => 'post_date',
            'value'    => $_GET['post_date']
        );
    }
    if (isset($_GET['order_status']) && $_GET['order_status'] != '') {
        // second meta key/value
        $meta_query[] = array (
            'key'      => 'order_status',
            'value'    => $_GET['order_status']
        );
    }
    $query->query_vars['meta_query'] = $meta_query; // add meta queries to $query
}
}

add_filter( 'parse_query', 'wpse454363_posts_filter' );
```